# Rapid SQL/Sybase Open Client 15 Error: "Unable to find an available protocol driver structure"

Tags: database, sybase, rapidsql

All,

After several months of not touching our databases I fired up Rapid SQL and get this error when I try and connect to a registered Sybase DB:

"Layer (5) Origin (3), Severity (5), Number (3) ct_connect(): network_packet_layer: internal net library error: Unable to find an available protocol driver structure"

Any ideas?  I'm running on a corporate desktop build so always possible that drivers and software are changed/installed etc every time I log on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that the Sybase System/Environment variable points to the latest version of sybase.
2. Rename an old Sybase installs to Old-Sybase12 etc.
3. Remove any old Sybase directories from your path.
4. Make sure your path contains the latest Sybase dirs.

Should do it.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Looks to be a language character-set not installed issue in my case.  Can't connect to a server running Shift-JIS, can connect to Latin-1 server fine.  If I get the other solution I'll post it.  -- Woops, then again it could be I fat-fingered the protocol name in sql.ini.  Problem solved.